# What is the best way to rewrite this query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

My query is

```
 select [ProductType], SUM(total) From isss
 group by [ProductType],total
```

i am getting following output

```
   CV   0
    RTV 0
    Audio   4
    CV  34
    RTV 10
    Audio   4
```

You can observe in output, producttypes are repaeating. how to get it right? i want total sum of CV, RTV and Audio

Comment: Why do you need to have `total` in the `group by`? Omit it & you will see that it works. Please read the SQL documentation on `group by`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT    [ProductType], 
          SUM(total) 
FROM      isss
GROUP BY  [ProductType]
```

Comment: :Thank you very much for quickly response and correct solution